# Error : argument of type "int" is incompatible with parameter of type "const void *"

Tags: cuda

in this part of my code when compile program. this error show: "argument of type "int" is incompatible with parameter of type "const void *". i declare variable as follow:

```
int *dev_matrix, *dev_array, *dev_array_length;
int array_length=1;
cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_array_length, 1*sizeof(int));
cudaMemcpy(dev_array_length, array_length, 1*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The second argument to [`cudaMemcpy()`](http://www.clear.rice.edu/comp422/resources/cuda/html/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g48efa06b81cc031b2aa6fdc2e9930741.html) is wrong. It is meant to be a pointer (`const void*`) and you're supplying an `int`.

Did you mean to write:

```
cudaMemcpy(dev_array_length, &array_length, 1*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
                             ^
```